# Basic gain cell

Tags: transistors, mosfet, cmos

[image]

Guys i was going through basic gain cell topic in my textbook. I came accross this circuit. Pls explain how v<sub>o</sub> is not equal to V<sub>DD</sub>. I mean how can they be different? There is no resistance that there will be a voltage drop. There is only a current source. Does voltage drop occur through current sources also? In book it says v<sub>o</sub> will be determined from feedback.

Comment: I think you are missing one very basic fact: a current source has infinite output impedance. There is actually no real need to draw \$V_{DD}\$ on this circuit.

Comment: In other words, a current source can have any voltage whatsoever across its terminals. There's no reason to assume it must be zero.

Comment: Post normal schematic! There is a special tool to draw schematics, edit Your post!

Answer (score 2):

If the current source produces 10mA and the MOSFET is trying to take 10.0001 mA then the voltage on the drain is approximately zero. If, on the other hand the MOSFET is trying to only take 9.9999 mA then the voltage on the drain is close to Vdd.

In practise, the MOSFET has an effective DS parallel resistance of several kohm so it's not quite as black and white as the initial paragraph paints.

Answer (score 0):

With MOSFETs, you need to consider that the gain is due to the drain voltage and the change in the effective channel length (sigma).  Below is an image that represents the behavior in subvt, even through it is not true to physics, in abovevt, it's the same but the bands are different due to the inverted channel and the gain is lower.

[image: common source]

If you have a fixed current, I, from a bias, the channel must change to satisfy the surface condition, which means that Vo is completely dependent on your drain term.

I would suggest looking under "common source amplifier" in either [Analog VLSI and Neural Systems by Carver Mead](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201059924) or [Analog VLSI: Circuits and Principles by Liu](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262122553) as those two books have the best explanation of the device behavior.  You'll probably need to check your University library.